Elegir el mínimo valor entre 2 datos en SQL
En este Case debo traer el mínimo valor entre las 2 sentencias.
Desde ya muy agradecido cualquier ayuda.
case

when c.cohade='impues' then isnull((select SUM(x.monto)+ 
(case
when h.Cod_isa=900 then ISNULL(ROUND(D.Ktim*0.07,0),0) 
when h.Cod_isa<900 then 
-- desde acá
MIN( (select x1.monto from rliquid x1 where x1.cohade='isapre' 
and x1.ames=c.ames and x1.codigo=c.Codigo) ,  
(Select round(((topeafp*uf)*0.07),0)    from RINDICES ri WHERE 
(select concat(ri.aa, (case when ri.mm<10 then concat('0', ri.mm) 
when ri.mm>9 then cast(ri.mm as varchar)end)))='202301')
-- hasta acá
end) 

from rliquid x where x.ames=c.ames  and x.codigo=c.codigo and x.cohade 
in('AFPCOT','SEGCET' )),0)

else '0' end as "Total de rebajas por LLSS",


Esa sentencia es una pesadilla. Es posible que busques la función LEAST() en vez de  MIN() pero tienes graves problemas de diseño en la consulta.

Creo que va a ser mucho mas facil, si nos explicas lo que quieres, nos das los datos de origen y buscamos algo mas facil para solucionar tu problema...

Debes agregar un [MCVE] con énfasis en lo mínimo. No tiene por qué ser el código literal en que estas trabajando, si no que un pequeño ejemplo que exponga tu problema

@Yussef porqué arruino la pregunta?? Ya se habían dejado como debe ser men. La query es la que es, eso tiene el OP, que quiere que se haga?? (¬_¬)

@Yussef pero usted es un PRO, siempre podemos hacerlo mejor en lugar de revertir men. Ahí está lo solicitado según el OP (lo que puso en negrita). Con un par de comentarios era suficiente.

Muchas gracias por las respuesta. Esto corresponde a una de las columnas de mi consulta y se requiere saber el monto mínimo de la cotización de salud o el tope del 7% de salud.  el conjunto de datos son 2.  Rliquid y índices.  La primera tiene los montos y la indices  indicadores para calcular el tope del mes.  entonces de esas 2 sentencias que están en negrita necesito saber cual es la menor.
